# How to efficiently recalculate iterative weighted center

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, logic

I'm trying to write a gradient ascent approach to divide all points on a polygon into two sets via a continuous line (something like the below, where our polygon is a circle and we partition such that all points above the secant line in the circle are in $S_1$ and all points below the secant line within the circle are in $S_2$).

[image: circle with secant line though it]

The algorithm changes the partition line (secant line in the above image) one pixel at a time. The input is the polygon and we output an optimal partition line, where optimal is defined by the loss function. The loss function that defines the gradient is a linear combination of the losses of the individual pixels. In order to define this loss function, each pixel must have values $w$ and $d$, where $w$ is the weight of this pixel (constant, given) and $d$ is the distance to the average weighted center (we could also define a normalized version $d_n = d/\bar{d}$).

**How would we calculate these values of $w, d, \text{and } d_n$ efficiently, given that we change the center with every step when we perturb the dividing line?**

Given a fixed center, it's fairly simple. Because moving the partition line moves the center, the best solution I could come up with was to use a stale center and update center every $s$ steps. I thought I've read a better approach to a similar problem, but I can't find a solution.

I'm not sure if I'm describing the problem well enough. I could try clarifying if any part is unclear

Comment: Can you define the problem more clearly?  I'm not sure what "partitioning a polygon" means concretely.  Please [edit] your question to provide a full, self-contained specification of the problem you're trying to solve.  It can be helpful to specify what are the inputs to the algorithm and the desired output.  What's the context for this?  Did you encounter this task somewhere, and if so, can you share  the source?  Is there a practical motivation? Why is it a requirement to use gradient ascent?

Comment: @D.W. I tried clarifying what you pointed out. Is it clear or would you like more clarification? I don't imagine this problem can be enumerated (nor can we use DP for large polygons), hence gradient ascent.

Comment: @aome I still did not understand what is the loss function you want to minimize?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami The loss function is a relatively complex linear combination. The part of the function I need help with optimizing is iteratively calculating the $w$, $d$, and $d_n$. We can imagine the loss function being the gradient of $d_n$, for simplicity, as it incorporates both $w$ and $d$

Comment: What do you call "points on a polygon" ? Are they the vertices ? Points on the edges ? Points that fill the inside ? Discrete or continuous points ? And what are those "pixels" ? Then you talk about a "continuous" line, but show a straight line (the same way you traded a circle for a polygon). You don't even say what the objective function to be optimized is. Sorry but about everything in your post is unclear.